# MongoDB Stitch vs Firebase Firestore AND/OR operations

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, mongodb-stitch

I mainly want to compare using firestore vs mongoDB Stitch queries.

I'm building an app (angular 5 + ios + android). The app is mainly of 2 views profile and feeds.

The profile contains an array of tags(all user post tags) and a timeline of his posts.

every post got its own array of tags and timestamp. so I can filter them.

filters are either AND / OR operation.

In firestore I plan to use object maps so the AND operation can work

In firestore in order to create  OR operation, I need to loop on all the possibilities fetch them individually,  aggregate the data and remove duplicates. This can be done on the frontend or inside a cloud function.

I also need to run analytics to know the trending tags every day.

If a user got 100s of posts. How will firestore compare to mongoDB Stitch regarding?

- Speed
- Cost

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: I revamped the question to be more specific